# Latest builds from Angular2 complain with: NgModule DynamicModule uses HomeComponent via "entryComponents"

Tags: angular

Since switching to the latest builds of Angular 2 (i.e. on github, master), I get warnings as follows about all my components:

> NgModule DynamicModule uses HomeComponent via "entryComponents" but it
>   was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error
>   after final.

I get the same error message for all my components, in addition to `HomeComponent`.

Can anyone please provide information about those?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The above warning is due to wrong usage of `@NgModule`. Using the `@NgModule` 's `entryComponents` attribute should sort this out.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This caught me out too. Significant changes in RC5 to the way that you route and bootstrap with a significant reliance on `app.module.ts` and `@NgModule` decorator. The documentation has been updated here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/ and the changelog here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Main changes to the routing file are changes to the `import` and `export` statements. A simple example is illustrated below which has two components, `AppComponent` and `HomeComponent`, that serves `HomeComponent` from  `index.html`:

File: app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`
```

You then need to use an NgModule file:

File: app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

import { routing }        from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then you need to pull in `AppModule` to `main.ts` and bootstrap using it.

File: main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`
```

This pattern does not produce the console warning message.

Comment: does it work? you should get error in app.routing.ts there is no import for HomeComponent ?

Comment: Worked for me. The [5 Min Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) is already up to speed with those changes. As one who recently followed it, I had to revisit it for more changes related to `NgModule`.  Thanks!

Comment: MrJSingh - you're right, have added in that missing import statement for HomeComponent.

Comment: The important piece is to declare the component in what regards to this message! declarations: [ AppComponent ],

Answer (score 11):

There's one other thing to be careful of with regard to this warning.

I was receiving it even though I was in fact declaring the component in my module and it was driving me up the wall because everything looked to be correct.

So I stepped through *compiler.umd.js* where the warning was getting generated and I noticed that the component for which I was getting the error was being added to the array of directives twice here:

```
 if (force || !transitiveModule.directivesSet.has(dirMeta.type.runtime)) {
            transitiveModule.directivesSet.add(dirMeta.type.runtime);
            transitiveModule.directives.push(dirMeta);
            declaredDirectives.push(dirMeta);
            this._addTypeToModule(dirMeta.type.runtime, moduleType);
            return true;
        }
```

Basically, even though the component was already in directivesSet, *transitiveModule.directivesSet.has(dirMeta.type.runtime)* was evaluating to false so it was getting added again and one of these was causing the warning to appear.

It turned out that the import statements in my routing file and my module file were slightly different. One capitalized the first letter of a directory in the path, whereas in the other the directory was in all lowercase like so:

```
//in routing
import { SomeComponent } from './Directory/some.component';

//in app module
import { SomeComponent } from './directory/some.component';
```

Once I changed so the paths matched, the warning went away. Everything else seemed to function properly with the mismatched casing.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this * 1000. This problem had me running in circles around my code for an entire working day. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely a tricky one that had me very frustrated. I've since discovered a good way to avoid the issue altogether is to use the '--forceConsistentCasingInFileNames' TypeScript compile option. This will bring to light any casing inconsistencies before they cause problems. (If you're working in VS the msbuild version of the compile option in the project file would be <TypeScriptForceConsistentCasingInFileNames>True</TypeScriptForceConsistentCasingInFileNames>).

Answer (score 7):

you also need to add every component in your routes to your NgModule declarations. Lots of boilerplate. See angular issue here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10472

Comment: I know you are right, but I really think this is a step back. So in the end I import every module that is necessary for routing there? I think this will get messy very fast. What if you have 20 routes. Maintainability is even worse than Angular 1.x like this.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue but on the testing part.

> WARN: 'Component RootCmp in NgModule DynamicTestModule uses BlankCmp
>   via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported into
>   the module! This warning will become an error after final.'

How to setup the DynamicTestModule ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading a large codebase then none of these answers tell you which component you forgot to add to **app.module.ts**

The closest answer (if this is your problem) is given by @doubletriplezero

He mentions that **compiler.umd.js** has some useful info.

In fact this can tell you exactly which component you forgot to import. See

[Angular 2 Component is not part of any NgModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527722/angular-2-component-is-not-part-of-any-ngmodule#answer-40135883)

for a fuller answer