# Precompile now causes error in RC 5 - Angular 2

Tags: angular

precompile is causing an error in RC5:

[image]

The error is

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; directives:
>   ((typeof RouterOutlet | typeof RouterLink | ...' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'ComponentMetadataType'.   Object literal may only
>   specify known properties, and 'precompile' does not exist in type
>   'ComponentMetadataType'. (property) precompile: typeof
>   LandingPageComponent[]

What is the recommendation that I do here? Delete the line in error? Add something that does the equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `precompile` has been renamed to `entryComponents`.

You can look at the following commit for further details:
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/6f4e49e

Or this question here on SO 
[Latest builds from Angular2 complain with: NgModule DynamicModule uses HomeComponent via "entryComponents"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749273/latest-builds-from-angular2-complain-with-ngmodule-dynamicmodule-uses-homecompo)