# Getting error while putting Route configuration in separate ts file in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-router

Getting below error when I am putting routing config details in a different ts  file. However it works fine if I put the route config in boot.ts file.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Component DashboardComponent is not part
>   of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
>   ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Component
>   DashboardComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not
>   been imported into your module.

**app.routing.ts:**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './Components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    enableTracing: true
});
```

**boot.ts**

```
//other imports
import { AppRouting } from './app.routing';
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule,
    //AppRouting,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true }), // <-- debugging purposes only
    AgGridModule.forRoot(),
    MaterialModule,
    SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot(),
    ToastyModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule,
    HttpModule, TreeModule, GrowlModule, FileUploadModule, InputTextModule, ButtonModule, ConfirmDialogModule, NgxChartsModule
    , AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'AIzaSyC9TWEHsjWT_QX_Rxl8VXtnnY582aY4mBQ' }) //Angular Google Map Setup
],
providers: [BaseComponentService, TreeNodeService, LowryToastyService],
declarations: [APP_COMPONENTS],
entryComponents: [ENTRY_COMPONENTS],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527722/angular-2-component-is-not-part-of-any-ngmodule  ->  "So the routes thinks its loading a different component then the module due to differences in the capitalization, which means the ones being pulled into the routes were not the same ones as the module."

Comment: thank u @mwager .It helped me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declare "DashboardComponent" in app.module.ts 
put this in your app.module.ts

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './Components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

declarations: [ DashboardComponent ]
```